# How to put condition inside map function

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm using geolib to get Point is within the circle, and the below function returns only TRUE/FALSE.

```
geolib.isPointWithinRadius(
    { latitude: 51.525, longitude: 7.4575 }, // My current location.
    { latitude: 51.5175, longitude: 7.4678 }, // returns TRUE if this point is within 5 km radius from my current location.
    5000
);
```

and yes it's working. But what i want is, i want to check multiple locations. for ex, i have below array, and i want to check the same function to check all the locaions, if any one of location is within 5 km from my locaion it should return TRUE. in other words, i will be getting FALSE only when none of the locations are within 5 km of my current location

```
const markers = [
    {
      title: "my location1",
      coordinates: {
        latitude: 14.599912,
        longitude: 24.1147557,
      },
    },
    {
      title: "my location 2",
      coordinates: {
        latitude: 34.599912,
        longitude: 44.1147557,
      },
    },
    {
      title: "my location 3",
      coordinates: {
     latitude: 54.599912,
        longitude: 64.1147557,
      },
    },
  ];
```

I tried this,

```
geolib.isPointWithinRadius(
    { latitude: 51.525, longitude: 7.4575 },
    markers.map((marker) => marker.coordinates),
    50
  );
```

i get only false, i would really appreciate your help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `some` method can be used to check if at least one item returns true:

```js
const isWithinRange = markers.some(marker => {
  return geolib.isPointWithinRadius(
    { latitude: 51.525, longitude: 7.4575 },
    marker.coordinates,
    50
  );
})
```

docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some

Comment: Great, it actually worked, but its says as a warning **Each child in a list should have a unique key prop**

Comment: That warning occurs if you use `map` in your render method and don't give each item a value for the `key` prop. The key should be something that uniquely identifies the row.

like: `items.map(item => <div key={item.id}>{item.name} {item.price}</div>)` or you can use the index if don't have an unique identifier: `items.map((item, index) => <div key={index}>{item.name}</div>`. Check the docs for more details: https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys

Comment: yes, i got it, but here it returns just a function. where ever i use key prop inside the function, i am getting error. i really hope u would give a hand on this.

Comment: Could you further clarify "key prop inside the function"? The key prop should be added to the element?

Comment: No.. the answer you gave me just exactly what i want, i just getting this warning go away. i dont need a key prop in element.

Comment: The key warning is caused by the logic in the render method, it is not caused by the snippet I have provided. The error should mention the line of the element that contains the element with missing key prop.

Comment: You are correct. I fixed that. I really admire you. Thank you so much.

Comment: No worries, good luck on your coding journey! You can mark the answer as solution(checkmark below downvote icon) to make it easier for others with a similar problem to find this solution.